# Some clarifications on gettext and i18n functions in wordpress ( or drupal for what it matters )

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, internationalization, gettext

Let's say i have an array.

```
$less_user_variables = array(
    "bodyBackground" => array( 
        "value" => "#ffffff",
        "description" => __( "Body background", AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
        "tab" => "general",
        "type" => "color",
    ),
```

i need to i18n the description. So i wrap it into a `__()` call. So when i create the .pot file "Body Background" is included. Now let's say i save the array to the db and later on retrieve it

```
$less_variables = get_option('less_variables');
```

can i use _*() again on the description to tranlsate it?I think that at runtime all that _*() does is actually check for a translation of the variable that it gets and for this reason

```
$description = __($less_variables["bodyBackground"]["description"], AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME );
```

Should give me the translation of "Body Background", am i right?The rule that `__()` can't be used with variables is just for creating the .pot files but at runtime it would work with a variable, am i right?
Or should i use each and every time the $less_user_variables original array?

One more thing that ( i think ) supports my thoughts is that

```
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    return translate( $text, $domain );
}
```

so if i pass a variable or a string, actually nothing changes. Am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

actually in your example, the $less_user_variables['bodyBackground']['description'] variable contains the translated text. So when you save the array, you actually save the translated value, so for accessing translated text, you just need to check $less_variables['bodyBackground']['description']

__() function is very simple as you can see - you put there string and recieve translated string

Comment: Yes you are right. But this would break if the site has the ability to switch languages. So i must not save the description but always use the original $less_user_variables

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would do this (after pot file generation) :

```
$less_user_variables = array(
    "bodyBackground" => array( 
        "value" => "#ffffff",
        "_description" => 'Body background',
        "tab" => "general",
        "type" => "color",
    ),
```

Just to be sure that `_description` contains the good string.

And after :

```
$less_variables = get_option('less_variables');
$less_variables['bodyBackground']['description'] = __($less_variables['bodyBackground']['_description'], AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME);
```